# Changes don't affect anything in reset.blade.php Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-blade

I have a very strange problem. I used the `php artisan make:auth` and when I change the reset.blade.php  it doesn't change anything in the output. I couldn't even change the layout even though I changed the `extends('layouts.app')` to my own layouts.master. I somehow managed to change it to my layouts.master view by deleting the layout.app view that comes with the scaffolding command. I have no problem changing the login and register view which I actually already changed. Has someone encountered such a problem? I find it very strange and I hope someone could help me. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8):

If you are trying to edit the view that is linked from the "Forgot Your Password?" link, then edit:

**/resources/views/auth/password/email.blade.php** 
(the view which contains the form to enter email address to start password reset process)

and **NOT**

**/resources/views/auth/password/reset.blade.php** 
(which is the view where you enter your new password, after clicking on link in password reset email).

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Try running `php artisan cache:clear`. Sounds like your views are hard cached.

Comment: I tried it earlier and I tried once again now. Nope. Sadly this didn't fix it.

Comment: If your cache is empty and the template is not updating I'm forced to assume you are editing the wrong template.

Comment: I already thought that. I deleted the reset.blade.php the reset.stub and it still OUTPUTS the reset view as it is by default. I just tried that on a fresh laravel project.

Comment: Are you modifying /resources/views/vendor/ files or the ones in the /vendor/ main directory? reset.stub should not exist in your app.

Comment: I am modifying the ones in my /resources/views folder. I am not modifying anything inside the /vendor folder. I just tried to deleting the stub to see what happens. I just don't know from where it takes the view. It should be  /resources/views/auth/passwords/reset.blade.php but there isn't one line of code there and it still works like everything is written.

Comment: I just deleted resets.blade.php and it still works. This might be a Laravel bug. Could you try it yourself on a fresh laravel project? Just run the auth command and try it.

Answer (score 0):

Since this issue could stil occur for some users, I would suggest using `npm run watch`. If you just want to compile your files a single time, use `npm run dev` or `npm run prod` for production files.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem.
It appears that in the .env file your variable APP_URL has to be correct.
Mine was not correctly named.

Greets

Comment: How do you know the OP is using .env?